# sum a column which the column name comes from another column's value

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to sum one of the columns which that column name comes from another column value (Col.2)

```
Col.1   Col.2   Q1  Q2  Q3
a   Q1  1   1   4
a   Q1  2   1   1
c   Q1  2   1   2
```

Haved tried case function seems no hope

```
select col.1, col.2, sum(case when col.2='Q1' then 'Q1',
when col.2='Q2' then 'Q2' end as Total)
from tabl
group by col.1, col.2

Col.1   Col.2   Q1
a   Q1  3
c   Q1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you may need:

```
select Col1, Col2,
        sum(
                case
                    when Col2='Q1' then Q1
                    when Col2='Q2' then Q2
                    else 0
                end
           ) as Total
from yourTable
group by Col1, Col2
```

For example, with your sample data:

```
with yourTable(Col1, Col2, Q1, Q2, Q3) as (
  select 'a',    'Q1',    1,    1,    4 from dual union all
  select 'a',    'Q1',    2,    1,    1 from dual union all
  select 'c',    'Q1',    2,    1,    2 from dual
)
select Col1, Col2,
        sum(
                case
                    when Col2='Q1' then Q1
                    when Col2='Q2' then Q2
                    else 0
                end
           ) as Total
from yourTable
group by Col1, Col2
```

gives:

```
COL1 COL2      TOTAL
---- ---- ----------
a    Q1            3
c    Q1            2
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But here it comes to another question. When I group by Col1, Col2 and order by Col1, Col2, the NULL value of Col1 comes to the last row. I want it to be placed at the first row. I tried to use "Order by Col1 NULLS FIRST, Col2" but the NULL value goes to the bottom. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `'Q1'` with `Q1` and `'Q2'` with `Q2`:

```
select col1
     , col2
     , sum(case
               when col2 = 'Q1' then Q1,
               when col2 = 'Q2' then Q2
           end) as Total
from tabl
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: When I group by Col1, Col2 and order by Col1, Col2, the NULL value of Col1 comes to the last row. I want it to be placed at the first row. I tried to use "Order by Col1 NULLS FIRST, Col2" but the NULL value goes to the bottom. Why?